# What is the use and sense of Meta Class used in Django under Models Section. Also Why and When we specify it and when not

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    lesson_name = models.ForeignKey(Lesson , null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    comm_name= models.CharField(max_length=100 , blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify("comment by" + "-" +str(self.author) + str(self.date_added))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def __str__(self):
         return self.comm_name
     
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']
```

Comment: I have fixed your code block, but your question isn't very clear. In general, questions that are just a dump of code with a title aren't a good fit here. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

According to django documentations:

> Model metadata is “anything that’s not a field”, such as ordering
> options (ordering), database table name (db_table), or human-readable
> singular and plural names (verbose_name and verbose_name_plural). None
> are required, and adding class Meta to a model is completely optional.

You can find all meta options [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/).

Comment: Unable to get what the documentation says! Thanks for answering and helping

Comment: It holds just meta options and Django uses them while migrating or making queries. For example, abstract = true tells Django to not create migrations for it or db_table tells Django to use a custom name for this table.

Comment: Then we need to define it in every form and model class to let Django know how to create queries, or we can skip for some(as we don't define for some models or forms)..?

Comment: No. if you want to modify Django models default behaviours you can do this.